# hive view with nested selects and partition pruning

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a view in HIVE with subselect - the purpose of the view is to remove dups from the source table.

The source table is partitioned by source_system column.

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS 
        SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT            
              *
              ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY source_system,key ORDER BY modification_date DESC) as seq_rn
            FROM mytable
        )  t
        WHERE seq_rn= 1
    ;
```

The problem is that if I do

```
EXPLAIN DEPENDENCY    SELECT * FROM myview WHERE source_system='AAA'
```

I see that all partitions are being scanned so partition pruning is not happening.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Try this: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/PartitionedViews#PartitionedViews-Syntax

Comment: can you give some input and output dataset.?

Comment: Some sample dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Workaround

As mentioned in the latest comment it is possible to build views for every filter.

---

#### Note, the following does not help

As mentioned in the comments it should be possible to solve this using partitioned views as documented here:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/PartitionedViews#PartitionedViews-Syntax

In case the partitioning does not extend to subqueries, try this:

1. Make a view with the inner query
2. Make a second view on top of that, with the outer query

I would normally not advocate building views on views, but if this is what it takes to let partitions work, this would of course justify the design choice.

Comment: thanks Dennis, I tried this and it did not work. Explain plan still does a full scan not using partitions within a view. I ended up building views for every filter - luckily in my case I only had 3 different filters. still a pain...

Comment: @mishkin Interesting, I have updated my answer though it is more of a workaround now, but will leave it in place for future reference.

Comment: actually I like your idea on making a view for inner select. I think this is the best workaround here. accepted your answer..